# C the value of an array getting modified sent by pointer after a void function

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I am currently trying to make moving average with C, and I want to send my address to the function and calculate the moving average inside the function. However, whenever I get out of the for loop inside the function, the pointer which was originally pointing at the initial array changes and I have no idea how to solve the problem. Here is my code:

```
include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define n 10
void monAvg(const float *in, float *out, int m);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
    {   
    float table_in[]={1,2,3,4,5,5,4,3,2,1};
    float table_out[]={0};

    if (argc != 2) {
      printf ("Incorrect number of program arguments");
      return 0;
    }

    if (atof(argv[1]) < 1 || atof(argv[1]) > n)) {
        printf ("Invalid program argument value");
        return 0;
    }


    monAvg(table_in, table_out, atof(argv[1]));

    return 0;
}

void monAvg(const float *in, float *out, int m) {

    float temp;
    int i,j;


    for (i = 0; i < (n - m + 1); i++) {
        temp = 0;
        for (j = i; j < i + m; j++) {
            temp += *(in + j);
        }
        *(out + i) = temp/m;

    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have undefined behavior: your output array has one item allocated, so processing the input of size above `1` causes writes past the allocated segment of `table_out`.

You can fix this by sizing the array explicitly:

```
float table_out[sizeof(table_in)/sizeof(table_in[0])]={0};
```

**Note:** Expression `sizeof(table_in)/sizeof(table_in[0])` computes the number of elements in `table_in`. You can use it in place of hard-coded `n`, which must be kept in sync with the count of `table_in` in order for your code to work correctly.